# How to write a program that produces the following output: 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127 in java

Tags: java

Write a program that produces the following output: 
3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127

I don't know how to frame it .

Comment: `System.out.println("3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127");`

Answer (score 0):

It increments the value with 4 8 16 32 64 and so on. So, it is easy.

```
    // that is clearly a parameter
    int inputLevel = 6;
    // first value. That can be a parameter as well.
    int value = 4; 
    while (i< inputLevel){
        System.out.println(value-1);
        value = value * 2 ;         
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Hmm and there I would have gone with with 2*(n-1)+1

Answer (score 0):

The addition is multiplying by two every step.

```
7 - 3 (second and first) = 4,
15 - 7 (third and second) = 8, 
31 - 15 (forth and third) = 16
```

and so on.

You can see that the difference is an ascending series

```
4, 8, 16 and continue - 32, 64
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your task here is to double the number and increment it by one until it's 127.

```
int n=3;
while (n < 127) {
    n=(n*2)+1;
    System.out.print(n + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple logic behind this.

```
static String generateSequence(int x){
        int temp =3;
        StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder("3,");
        for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
            temp = (int) (temp + Math.pow(2, i+1)); 
            result.append(String.valueOf(temp)+",");
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

above function will take parameter that is length of series that you want.

function call

```
System.out.println(generateSequence(5));
```

output : 
3,7,15,31,63,

function call 2

System.out.println(generateSequence(6));

3,7,15,31,63,127,

Answer (score -3):

You could use a : JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127")

Else you'll have to instanciate a frame, a jpanel, and inside the jpanel put something like a : JLabel lab = new JLabel("3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127")